# Recieving input file and storing it as a 2D list in Python?

Tags: python

My program needs to take in a .dat or .txt file that contains a "board" , I need to read in and store the board in a 2D list.

Example text file for board:

```
+---+-----+
|   |     |
|   |=====|
|   |     |
+---+-----+
```

My question is , how would I convert this file into a 2D list so I can fill in the gaps with specific symbols.Like auto-fill in MS Paint.

Comment: What's the difference between `.dat` and `.txt`?

Comment: its not clear what you are asking ...

Comment: What would the list look like for the example board?

Comment: Im not sure, I thought there would be a way I could convert all the strings in the file directly into a 2D list. Without starting from scratch.

Comment: Have a look at [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

Comment: `map(list,open("some_file.txt"))`

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a string to the `list` function, it takes each character in the string, and makes it a separate element of a list:

```
>>> list('hello')
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

A list comprehension is a way of creating a list whilst iterating over some sequence to create the list's elements:

```
>>> [x * 2 for x in range(1, 5)]
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

To demonstrate we'll use two useful Python facilities, `StringIO` and `pprint`. `StringIO` allows us to define the contents of a file-like object, so we can test code without actually creating the file. `pprint` pretty prints, which amongst other things wraps `lists` nicely so they fit on the screen.

We can split the `StringIO` contents based on the newline character, '\n':

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> from pprint import pprint

>>> contents = StringIO("""+---+-----+
... |   |     |
... |   |=====|
... |   |     |
... +---+-----+""")

>>> matrix = [list(line.strip()) for line in contents]
>>> pprint(matrix)
[['+', '-', '-', '-', '+', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '+'],
 ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'],
 ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', '=', '=', '=', '=', '=', '|'],
 ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'],
 ['+', '-', '-', '-', '+', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '+']]
```

Comment: Thank you. I am currently not allowed to import those at the time. So when I try to use the your code , it gives me an error.  "AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split' "

Answer (score 0):

Files are iterable objects that yield their lines. So all you need to do is:

```
strlist = list(fp)
```

If you need each character in a separate item of a list, then use a list comprehension that stuffs each line into a list (thus, you will have a list of lists of individual characters):

```
strlist = [list(line) for line in fp]
```

If you need to strip off the new lines:

```
strlist = [list(line.rstrip('\n')) for line in fp]
```

This, of course, assumes you have already opened the file with:

```
fp = open(filepath, mode='rb')
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a full example:

```
with open('/path/to/my/board.txt', mode='rb') as fp:
    strlist = [list(line.rstrip('\n')) for line in fp]

# What is in the top left corner of the grid.
print(strlist[0][0])
```

Comment: Im still a bit confused, is this going to give me a 2D list ? I am trying to make it so I take the text file and store it as a 2D board using rows and cols .

Comment: @j.sinu: Yes, this will give you a 2D list. In other words, a list of lists of characters. I will update with a full example.

Comment: thank you! Is there a way to rewrite the "with" using a for?

Comment: @j.sinu: The `with` statement makes sure to close the file object after leaving the block; it does not have anything to do with `for` loops. The `for` loop is not needed because the list comprehension is (in essence) a `for` loop.